# Use Docker with same port as other program

Tags: docker, networking, trace, zipkin

I am currently facing following problem:
I build a docker container of a node server (a simple express server which sends tracing data to Zipkin on port 9411) and want to run it along Zipkin.
So as I understood, the node server should send tracing data to Zipkin using port 9411.
If I run the server with node only (not as docker), I can run it along Zipkin and everything is working fine.
But if I got Zipkin running and than want to fire up my Docker Container, I get the error

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:9411: bind: address already in use.

My understanding is that there is a conflict concerning the port 9411, since it seems to be blocked by Zipkin, but obviously, also the server in the Docker container needs to use it to communicate with Zipkin.

I would appreciate if anybody got an idea how I could solve this problem.

Greetings,
Robert

Comment: What are the `docker run` command(s) you're using?  You only need a `-p` option if you're accepting inbound connections from outside container space; if your application container is merely _sending_ traces to port 9411, it does not need a `-p` option.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a docker container, you add a port binding like this:

```sh
docker run ... -p 8000:9000
```

where 8000 is the port you can use on the pc to access port 9000 within the container.

Don't bind the express server to 9411 as zipkin is already using that port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly I dont think this is the solution. I am aware about port bindings and the server it self is bindet on -p 8080:5555 (so the node server is listening on 5555 and accessiable on 8080). But I also need to do something about port 9411, since I still need it for the communication with Zipkin, but I don't know what to do...

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: using the flag --network="host" does the job, -p also is not needed.

Comment: This completely disables Docker networking; you lose several important options by doing this, and it doesn't seem like it should be necessary for the setup you describe.

Comment: Hmm, this Trulli sounds not perfect. You got any ideas how to archive a similar result?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).